# Compass won't compile any stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compass-sass

I recently implemented compass into a rails 3.0x app. I created an assets group in my gemfile and added compass-rails:

```
group :assets do
  gem "compass-rails"
end
```

I then ran `bundle exec compass init rails .` from the root of my app. It created the `print.css`, `ie.css`, etc.

However, it doesn't seem to compile my changes. Most importantly, I had an existing .scss file that I need to be compiled as well. But none of them are being watched. What do I need to do to have it update my css files when I edit my scss files?

My .scss files are stored in `app/assets/stylesheets` and my css files are stored in `public/stylesheets`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [gem documentation](https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails#rails-30-caveats):

**Rails 3.0 Caveats**

If you want rails to compile your stylesheets (instead of using the compass watcher) you need to edit `config/application.rb` and change:

```
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
```

to this:

```
Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
```